# Different integers? c#

Tags: c#, integer

I'm trying to read and extract specific information from several data files in which the filename format remains the same for every one, the format of my file is, XXXXXX_XXXXXX_PCPDTB_ODT.datafile where X is a random digit.

It represents year, month, day in the first 6 digits and hours, minutes and seconds in the last 6 X's, so 131005_091429_PCPDTB_ODT.datafile would be 2013, 10th month, 5th day and so on, the _PCPDTB_ODT.datafile is always there.

I'm able to gather my desired data (extracting all information after a certain keyword, in this case '#Footer' is my keyword) from a file successfully, but I'm not sure how I'd go about this with lots of files with several changing integers?

Here is my attempt (although it is terrible since I have very little experience of coding), but only seem to be to input 4 digits and no more. Which would only allow to access files like XXXX_PCPDTB_ODT.datafile or 1304_PCPDTB_ODT.datafile.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = @"C:\Users\#####\Desktop\";
        var ext = "_PCPDTB_ODT.datafile";
        var range = Enumerable.Range(0,9);
        var filePaths = 
                from i1 in range
                from i2 in range
                from i3 in range
                from i4 in range
                let file = path + i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + ext
                where File.Exists(file)
                select File.ReadLines(file)
                    .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("#Footer"))
                    .Skip(1);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,filePaths.SelectMany(f => f)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

I've attempted adding more i values, i5, i6, i7 etc. with "_" to space the first six digits from the last 6 but it doesn't seem to do anything when using the larger i values past i4.

Any ideas would help greatly, please keep in mind my coding is most likely rubbish since my knowledge is very little at the moment, thanks.

Comment: Any reason you're not finding all the files in the directory using `Directory.GetFiles`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I answered this same question a few hours ago. Using `GetFiles`, but I just don't understand why that isn't workable.

Comment: Personally, I'd turn this around and get all the files in the specified directory using [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) first and then iterate through those rather than trying every possible file name. Likely you have many more possible files name than you have actual file names.

Comment: Take the advice you've received now 4 times. Use `GetFiles` and filter as necessary. There is no need to iterate through possible permutations when you have a file name that ends in `datafile`. That's such a unique extension there is no way it conflicts with anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sorry about the way I was doing it, it was just a friend noted down a way to do it, but it obviously turns out his method wasn't very practical, working smoothly, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to process all of the files in a directory, use [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Forexample:

```
foreach (var filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\mydata\", "*PCPDTB_ODT.data")
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines(filename)
               .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("#Footer"))
               .Skip(1);
    // add the rest of your code . . .
}
```

Comment: This won't compile as-is (`select` keyword needs to be part of a LINQ query), but the idea is sound.

Comment: @TimS., are you sure about that? `File.ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to loop through every possible valid file name, you should just see what files are there. Here's an example using [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + ext)
                  .Select(file => File.ReadLines(file)
                    .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("#Footer"))
                    .Skip(1));
```

If you need the date/time also, you can parse that out, too, with [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't seem to do anything when using the larger i values past i4

Proavbly because it's having to iterate through 1,000,000,000,000 different filenames?

Why not just get a list of files that match the pattern?

```
    var path = @"C:\Users\#####\Desktop\";
    var pattern = "??????_??????_PCPDTB_ODT.datafile";

     var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern)
                              .Select(file => File.ReadLines(file)
                              .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("#Footer"))
                              .Skip(1));
```

Comment: This guy has gotten this advice now 4 times. There's nothing more we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;

public class Test
{
public static void Main()
{
    string str = "131005_091429_PCPDTB_ODT.datafile ";
    int[] date = new int[3];
    int[] time = new int[3];

    string[] arr = str.Split('_');
    for(int i = 0;i<6;i=i+2)
    {
        date[i/2]=Convert.ToInt32(arr[0].Substring(i,2));
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<6;i=i+2)
    {
        time[i/2]=Convert.ToInt32(arr[1].Substring(i,2));
    }
}
}
```